# How to pass through prop containing image path in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to display an image in Vue template using a prop that i passed through in my App.vue file.

App.vue:

`<Header image='../assets/logo.png' />`

Header.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="div-box">
    <img :src={image} alt="Vue logo" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Header",
  props: ["image"],
};
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to explicitly load the image "module":

```html
<Header :image="require('../assets/logo.png')" />
```

`vue-loader` does this [automatically](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html) for you for things like `<img>`, but if you've made your own component then you need to do it yourself.